# How to get the most recent record from a LEFT OUTER JOIN in Rails 3

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, left-join

I have two models:

Users & Posts (where users has_many posts)

I need to get a list of users ordered by who has the less recent post (including the ones that have NONE posts at the top of the list).

So far I managed to do something like this:

```
@users = User
          .joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN posts ON users.id = posts.user_id")
          .group("users.id")
          .order("posts.created_at ASC")
          .page(params[:page])
```

That is putting the ones without any post at the top but the rest are not being sorted. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way to accomplish this using plain activerecord. My solution was:

```
@users = User.find_by_sql(%q{
                SELECT users.*
                FROM users 
                LEFT OUTER JOIN (
                                  SELECT user_id, MAX(created_at) as max_created_at
                                  FROM posts
                                  GROUP BY user_id
                                ) AS posts_sq
                ON posts_sq.user_id = users.id
                LEFT OUTER JOIN posts AS posts
                  ON posts.user_id = posts_sq.user_id
                 AND posts.created_at = posts_sq.max_created_at
                WHERE deleted = false
                ORDER BY posts.id IS NULL DESC, posts.created_at DESC
                }).paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT tc.id, tc.name, tc.order, 
th.id as history_id, th.finished_at, th.score
FROM trainings tc
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT id, training_id, MAX(finished_at) as finished_at, score 
    FROM training_histories GROUP BY training_id) th ON th.training_id = tc.id
WHERE tc.id > 4
AND tc.id < 8
GROUP BY tc.id
ORDER BY tc.order_by ASC, tc.id ASC
```

Change your attributes as per your requirements.